# Problems with getting the properties of an ID when looping over all Ids

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm interested to get the properties of all dbId elements. For this purpose I'm simply looping over my array of dbIds and use the `getProperties` function provided by the [Forge Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/).

```
  someFunction() {

    const instanceTree = this.viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;

    const allDbIds = Object.keys(instanceTree.nodeAccess.dbIdToIndex);

    console.log('all DbIds');
    console.log(allDbIds);

    // This will give the correct Properties
    // this.viewer.getProperties(5, (result) => {
    //   console.log(result)
    // })

    allDbIds.forEach((dbId) => {

      this.viewer.getProperties(dbId, (result) => {
        console.log('result:');
        console.log(result);

      }, (err) => {
        console.log('err');
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

When I access a specific dbId directly I get the correct property array. However when looping over all dbIds and calling the `getProperties` function only the first two dbIds are returning properties and all the others are only returning empty arrays. Additionally the first two arrays are way to big and seem to contain the other properties. --> [Link to console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2uqC.jpg)

Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks already!

Comment: looks and sounds like a synchronisation / async issue...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating properties on the client page, a better approach might be to query all properties at once via the Model Derivative API. See these references:

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/